# Numerical study of Hubbard Model and Spin Charge Separation effect

Tags: condensed-matter, quantum-spin, ground-state

[image]

Hi,
**How can i implement the creation operator effect on the ground state**(in FORTRAN)?
we calculate the ground state using modified Lanczos method,and we obtain a vector(array) with lots of numbers in it,**what does this numbers mean?**

As an example for a system with **two sites and two electrons**,this is the way i build my Hilbert space:
[image]

And Here is the **Hopping term Matrix:**
[image]

Comment: Your question seems to be more about software and/or programming. It would be better if you could make it clear which bit of physics you need help with.

Comment: the problem is i do not get what will happen to our system when we add an electron to it(Single electron excitation?)? ,and when we find the ground state before adding the electron,what is the physical interpretation of those numbers in GS vector?how the system changes and what is the relation between new and old systems?

Comment: You need to find out what basis the GS vector is written in. That tells you what the numbers mean. Try talking to whoever you got the code from, assuming the code is not well-documented enough to work it our for yourself.

Comment: the code is written by me,i'm trying to drive this article:http://journals.aps.org/prb/abstract/10.1103/PhysRevB.47.5849
and i'm wondering how should i put equation(2) in my program.

Comment: Right, well then you should know what the numbers mean: they are components of the wavefunction in whatever basis it is written in the code. Now you find out the matrix elements of the operator $c^{\dagger}_{i,\uparrow}$ in this basis. This gives you a matrix that you apply to the GS wavefunction to get Eq. 2.

Comment: thanks for your careful answer.let's see what will happen!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first step, probably you have already know, is to get the ground state.

We may write the Hamiltonian on a set of orthogonal basis, e.g., 
$$\left| n_{1,\uparrow} n_{2,\uparrow} \cdots n_{N,\uparrow}, n_{1,\downarrow} n_{2,\downarrow} \cdots n_{N,\downarrow} \right\rangle =\prod_{i} (c_{i,\uparrow}^{\dagger})^{n_{i,\uparrow}} \prod_{i} (c_{i,\downarrow}^{\dagger})^{n_{i,\downarrow}} \left| 0 \right>.$$ Here $\left| 0 \right\rangle$ is the vacuum state. $n_{i,\uparrow}$ and $n_{i,\downarrow}$ can be either 0 or 1. Since the system has $N_e$ electrons, we have $$\sum_{i} (n_{i,\uparrow}+n_{i,\downarrow})=N_{e,\uparrow}+N_{e,\downarrow}=N_e.$$ The dimension of the Hilbert space is given by $D=\sum_{\max(N_{e}-N,0)\leq N_{e,\uparrow} \leq \min(N_e,N)} C_{N}^{N_{e,\uparrow}} C_{N}^{N_e-N_{e,\uparrow}}$. On this basis, the Hamiltonian becomes a $D\times D$ matrix. We can get the ground state by diagonalizing this matrix. Finally the ground state looks like $$\left| \varphi_0 \right\rangle =\sum_{\{n_{1,\uparrow} n_{2,\uparrow} \cdots n_{N,\uparrow}, n_{1,\downarrow} n_{2,\downarrow} \cdots n_{N,\downarrow} \}} f\left(n_{1,\uparrow} n_{2,\uparrow} \cdots n_{N,\uparrow}, n_{1,\downarrow} n_{2,\downarrow} \cdots n_{N,\downarrow}\right)\prod_{i} (c_{i,\uparrow}^{\dagger})^{n_{i,\uparrow}} \prod_{i} (c_{i,\downarrow}^{\dagger})^{n_{i,\downarrow}} \left| 0 \right>. $$ $f\left(n_{1,\uparrow} n_{2,\uparrow} \cdots n_{N,\uparrow}, n_{1,\downarrow} n_{2,\downarrow} \cdots n_{N,\downarrow}\right)$ are the numbers in the vector you get.

The next step is to add a spin-up electron to the system. Then the total number of electrons becomes $N_e'=N_e+1$. In particular, $N_{e,\uparrow}'=N_{e,\uparrow}+1$ and $N_{e,\downarrow}'=N_{e,\downarrow}$. Now you may set a new set of orthogonal basis with $N_e'$ electrons. The basis can be written similarly as before, except $N_e \rightarrow N_{e}'$. Correspondingly, the dimension of the new Hilbert space becomes $D'$. After that, we express the Hamiltonian and Eq. (2) on the new basis, and do the rest calculations on the new basis. Using second quantization, it is easy to find the relation between the coefficients $f$ in the old basis and the coefficients $f'$ in the new basis. For example, suppose one term in the ground state vector is $$ f c_{1,\uparrow}^{\dagger} c_{3,\downarrow}^{\dagger} \left| 0\right\rangle.$$ Now you want to add a spin-up electron at site 2. The new term becomes $$c_{2,\uparrow}^{\dagger} \left[f c_{1,\uparrow}^{\dagger} c_{3,\downarrow}^{\dagger} \left| 0\right\rangle \right]=-f c_{1,\uparrow}^{\dagger} c_{2,\uparrow}^{\dagger} c_{3,\downarrow}^{\dagger} \left| 0\right\rangle = f' c_{1,\uparrow}^{\dagger} c_{2,\uparrow}^{\dagger} c_{3,\downarrow}^{\dagger} \left| 0\right\rangle.$$ Here I assume one term in your new basis is $c_{1,\uparrow}^{\dagger} c_{2,\uparrow}^{\dagger} c_{3,\downarrow}^{\dagger} \left| 0\right\rangle$. Therefore, in this case $f'=-f$. For each term in the ground state vector, you may do something similar. Finally you will get the new wave function Eq. (2) in the new basis.

In this way, you can implement the creation operator effect on the ground state.

Comment: So let's assume that we have 2 electrons (one is up and the other is down),with 4 sites,so the dimension of the Hilbert space is 16.It's easy to find the lowest eigenvalue and the corresponding eigenvector.So are you telling me I have to find a new GS for my new configuration(2 up electrons and one down,so the dimension is 24)?I'm starting to feel so dumb!Could you please show how to get the coefficients that relates two systems?

Comment: @MoeinN.Ivaki Yes, I think you need to express Eq. (2) in the new configuration basis with 2 spin-up and 1 spin-down electrons. As to your second question, I have just added it in the answer part. Please see the new answer for details.

Comment: and now the conclusion!:
1.Normalizing the old GS
2.finding the GS vector after adding one up electron,and do the sum for each creation operator,where f' is f,-f or zero.
Am I right?
and as a final and fundamental(!) question,where these f came from?
I'm sorry for I'm not so smart!
thanks a million!

Comment: Yes, you are right. In your question you said "we calculate the ground state using modified Lanczos method,and we obtain a vector(array) with lots of numbers in it,what does this numbers mean?" So "f" are the numbers in your ground state vector.

Comment: Thank you very much,you taught
me what to do flawlessly.I appreciate your patient.